# Casting a const parameter in a function pointer to a non const in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, constants

I have a function that behaves almost the same whether I do a call to read(...) or write(...) that handles transfers to and from a file descriptor. I want to write a function like this:

```
uint32_t handleTX(ssize_t (*func)(int, void *, size_t));
```

I also have two functions:

```
uint32_t myRead() { return handleTX(::read); }
uint32_t myWrite() { return handleTX(::write); }
```

This is using the functions declared in unistd.h. The problem with this is that write(...) uses a 'const void *buf' whereas read(...) uses a 'void *buf'. Thus the two function signatures don't match. Is there a way I can cast the function signature to something to make them match? I thought about casting the function pointer to a (void *), but it doesn't seem the most elegant. Alternatively, I could make handleTX(...) a macro, but again it's not very clean. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The `read` and `write` functions might have *similar* signatures, but they are semantically very different (as indicated by their arguments). How would `handleTX` be able to handle those very different functions?

Comment: As for your problem, you might want to take a look at how many standard C++ functions handles unknown "functions", for example [`std::for_each`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly improper to have a universal signature like that. These functions do completely different things and do different interpretation of the parameter. Getting rid of const isn't the correct approach.

If your goal is to be transparent for the function and simply add your own prefix-postfix things around the given function, the simplest method is to do:

```
template <class Function>
uint32_t handleTX(Function f)
{
     ... do whatever you need
     n = f(fd, data, size);
}

uint32_t myRead() { return handleTX(::read); }
uint32_t myWrite() { return handleTX(::write); }
```

Whether it will work depends on whether 'data' is always mutable. This will match both.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own trivial wrapper for `write()` which takes a non-const data pointer.  Then you can pass that to `handleTX()`.

Answer (score 0):

As John Zwinck said, you can use a wrapper for `write()` alone, or you could implement wrapper for both `read()` and `write()` to completely abstract `read()` and `write()` from `unistd.h`

Instead of function pointers, you could have used enum's to differentiate `read()` and `write()` operation by `handleTX()`

Answer (score -1):

template 
uint32_t handleTX(Function f)
{
... do whatever you need
n = f(fd, data, size);
}

uint32_t myRead() { return handleTX(::read); }
uint32_t myWrite() { return handleTX(::write); }

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).